# "Diff" is always showing space at the end of line in code blocks when code block line is edited

Tags: bug, status-completed

This happens in suggested-edits, I didn't look at others
http://phpcode.eu/images/1316004041.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When tokenizing the text for running the diff engine over the tokens, lengths of white space are condensed into a single token. So in [your case](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/105681), the token that had changed included the newline character. In code blocks this looks weird, because here a newline actually has a meaning (unlike in normal HTML text, where it's just like any other whitespace).

The next build fixes this, so only if a newline is actually added will this be visible, like this (hypothetical) edit:

[image: image of a diff with a whitespace change]